# How can I change the order of the rows in an Oracle Database? (Order By not an option)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I reorder rows in oracle sql database?  I am using a 3rd party database-driven software and unfortunately I cannot change the call (or I would just add an order by), but can I change the order of the rows in the database?

Disclaimer: I know I should never depend on raw database order, and if it changes I understand, but can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Make a view and point the 3rd party software to that?

Comment: No ability to point it to a view, I'll have to look into changing the schema.

Comment: Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted. So you can't "re-order" them.

Comment: In 12c you could try the SQL Translation Framework - allows you to change SQL out on-the-fly. http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2013/07/sql-translation-framework/

Comment: No ability to point to a view? Even if you rename the source table and replace it with a view with triggers that make the view updateable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  If a query doesn't specify an `ORDER BY`, the order in which rows are returned is undefined.

If you are willing to accept a less-than-100% solution, you could try moving the data to a temporary table, truncate the table, and then insert the data back in the order you want it to appear.  If the query is doing a table scan or some type of index scans and not doing anything complicated (like a join), it's likely that the rows would be returned in the order they are physically stored in the table.  No guarantees, of course, but it might work most of the time.

Comment: I never worked with them so far but if understand it right Index Organized Tables could do the trick or not? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg07iot.htm

Comment: @evilive: no, IOTs won't help. The ***only*** way to get a specific order is to use `ORDER BY`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Could you please shortly explain why, as the posted link above says: "A row in an index-organized table does not have a stable physical location. It keeps data in sorted order, in the leaves of a B*-tree index built on the table's primary key. These rows can move around to preserve the sorted order. For example, an insertion can cause an existing row to move to a different slot, or even to a different block." So choosing your primary key (and rebuilding the whole table) you should be able to achieve a fixed order, or not?

Comment: @evilive: the fact that the rows are *stored* in a sorted manner does not guarantee you that Oracle will *retrieve* them in that order. You can even get "un-ordered" rows from an index scan.

Comment: @Justin: dumping them into a temp table might actually do the trick, I'll give it a try, thanks!